# Facebook Login - Recving "User cancelled login" on android

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to implement Facebook Login for Unity.
I used the following example from facebook SDK for unity:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples/

In editor it seems to be working (which is more for testing purposes) as i can see from console, However, from Android i receive the following image:
 [image: From Android device]

When I click "OK" I receive "User cancelled login" which I see from console 'ADB' debugging, in actually APP nothing happens.
You can see the "User cancelled login" line of code in the Link for Facebook SDK for unity I provided.

My question, is that how FB LOGIN should look like? I thought it should open Facebook login page.
Where am i going wrong?

**Code:**

```
  public void OnClick_PromptFaceBookLogin()
    {
        List<string> perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email" };
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);

    }

    private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) //Android Not passing this, while in editor it does pass
        {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log("userid="+aToken.UserId);
            Debug.Log("TokenString=" + aToken.TokenString);

            AuthModel.LoginFaceBook(aToken.TokenString);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions)
            {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }
```

**Facebook SDK settings:**

[image: Facebook SDK settings]

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @StevenCoull Done :)

Comment: Thanks! Are you initializing the SDK as mentioned in the example?

Comment: yes, i skipped that in the code here.

Comment: Assuming your initialization is okay, your code should run fine. You're right, normally when the LogInWithReadPermissions() method is called the Facebook login page opens.
Have you set your client token & app ID in the Facebook Settings area, and generated the android manifest?

Comment: I believe so (Added FB settings SDK image to question). I did click "Generate Android Manifest", however, I do not see all that data like "Debug Android Key Hash" in the Manifest file.

Comment: Were you able to login using the example scene provided with the SDK? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted

Comment: Also the debug hash key won't be in the manifest, just a list of the activities, ApplicationId, and provider.

Comment: It seems so,
In the log i get OnInitCompleteCalled IsLoggedIn='False' IsInitialized='True'
And status in main scene is "Success - check log for details", IsLoggedIn is False, but i think this is how it is in editor?

Answer (score 0):

Okey,

Issue was that the `Debug Android Key Hash` in Facebook Settings (Facebook -> Edit Settings) was Incorrect!

[image]

I found out that by trying to build the `MainMenu.scene` in Facebook examples in the project. This helps to debug and find problems, like in our case.

**Note**: Do not forget to add `LogView.scene` to 'Scenes in build' as this is where you can see the real hash (After pressing '**log**' button in the MainMenu Scene).

afterwards, go to your app Facebook developer page. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID]
**Settings -> Basic -> Key Hashes (place the correct hash here)**

Walla, it works.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thank you @StevenCoull, your questions and suggestions helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues here, but it turns out that there has an extra "space" character when I copy the APPId from face book app setting page, so the AppId wont match the same appId in the facebook app settings page and cause the issues.

It took me a lot of time to solve the issues lol.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phzr2.jpg)